# Is it possible to harvest a p-n junction diode crystal from a MOSFET?

Tags: power-electronics, lasers

I am currently looking for a quick source of Silicon Carbide p-n junction crystals. I saw this video where an off the shelf MOSFET is decapped using a fiber laser:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q8uug2xmdXQ

I was wondering if this would damage the p-n crystal to the point where it would no longer act as a diode, or if it would still maintain some of its properties.

Comment: MOSFET doping or operation does not form a diode connection.

Comment: MOSFETs are 2 p-type semiconductors separated by an n-type. its that junction between the p and the n type SiC that I am calling a diode. Also the part that I am interested in (also apparently I cant get back to the old account)